# html:Need the selected column highlighted stay

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

In the html of ionic framework, I need the highlighted division to stay there when selected. However, it only highlighted when I am click on the div and then it will disappear.

It is hard to differentiate what I am selected.

**html**

```
  <div class="col col-33" ng-click="reverse = (orderWith=='Stock')? !reverse: reverse;orderWith='Stock'" >Stock<i class="icon" style="float:left" ng-class="{'ion-chevron-down': reverse, 'ion-chevron-up': !reverse}"></i></div>
    <div class="col" ng-click="reverse = (orderWith=='Trade')? !reverse: reverse;orderWith='Trade'">Call<i class="icon" style="float:left" ng-class="{'ion-chevron-down': reverse, 'ion-chevron-up': !reverse}"></i></div>
    <div class="col" ng-click="reverse = (orderWith=='Price')? !reverse: reverse;orderWith='Price'">Price<i class="icon" style="float:left" ng-class="{'ion-chevron-down': reverse, 'ion-chevron-up': !reverse}"></i></div>
```

**css**

```
 .col{
  border-right: solid 1px #3f56a8;
  padding-top: .35em;
}
.col:active{
  background-color: #1b4e84;
    color:aqua !important;
}
```

I change active to focus but it does not work at all